# Fill width of panel with rectangles(variable size)

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I'm making a sorting algorithm vizualizer(Like [Sound of Sorting](http://panthema.net/2013/sound-of-sorting/) without the Sound) But i stumbled upon a problem, and i can't seem to figure it out. I need to layout rectangles over the width of a panel(variable amount).

Image of the bars:

[image: Image of the bars]

But when i get more bars, sometimes i will get a blank space because it won't fit:

[image]

How can i make it that some rectangles are a bit bigger than some others to make it fit? The way i calculate the width right now is like this:

```
barWidth = draw.Width / amount; //draw is the panel where i draw the rectangles on
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a rounding issue so I think you need to do some calulations:

1. totalBarWidth = sum of barWidths
2. blankSpace = draw.Width - totalBarWidth
3. numberOfBarsPerBlankSpacePixel = amount / blank space
4. Loop over the bars and add a pixel to the width of every numberOfBarsPerBlankSpacePixel bars.

Also don't forget to add the pixels to the x-axis location of the following bars.

Comment: Thanks, it does work, but i think i'll make it so the form resizes.. Because it  looks kinda wierd [image](http://lnsrt.me/0e)